# Speed up xls editor in Node.js

Tags: node.js, performance

I have a module that change some data in xls files and then save the changes. Depending on the size of the files, this process can take a lot of time. It comes to the fact that the module simply can not withstand the load and falls.

```
<--- Last few GCs --->

[15924:000000000042E850]    66070 ms: Scavenge 1384.7 (1420.4) -> 1384.0 (1420.4) MB, 3.3 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.251, current mu = 0.351) allocation failure
[15924:000000000042E850]    66084 ms: Scavenge 1384.8 (1420.4) -> 1384.2 (1420.9) MB, 2.9 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.251, current mu = 0.351) allocation failure
[15924:000000000042E850]    66102 ms: Scavenge 1385.0 (1420.9) -> 1384.4 (1420.9) MB, 3.9 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.251, current mu = 0.351) allocation failure


<--- JS stacktrace --->

==== JS stack trace =========================================

    0: ExitFrame [pc: 0000038C7C65C5C1]
Security context: 0x039ef4f1e6e1 <JSObject>
    1: read_shift(aka ReadShift) [000000D579360EC1] [D:\RAMDISK\tests\node_modules\xlsx\xlsx.js:~3217] [pc=0000038C7CEE2597](this=0x020bbafa27d1 <Uint8Array map = 000003D111D6F1D9>,size=1,t=0x031daf2026f1 <undefined>)
    2: arguments adaptor frame: 1->2
    3: f(aka parse_Row) [00000399FB6F4259] [D:\RAMDISK\tests...

FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
 1: 000000013F5508AA v8::internal::GCIdleTimeHandler::GCIdleTimeHandler+4810
 2: 000000013F529C46 node::MakeCallback+4518
 3: 000000013F52A630 node_module_register+2160
 4: 000000013F7BAA4E v8::internal::FatalProcessOutOfMemory+846
 5: 000000013F7BA97F v8::internal::FatalProcessOutOfMemory+639
 6: 000000013FCF8984 v8::internal::Heap::MaxHeapGrowingFactor+11476
 7: 000000013FCEF0E7 v8::internal::ScavengeJob::operator=+25543
 8: 000000013FCED65C v8::internal::ScavengeJob::operator=+18748
 9: 000000013FCEBF57 v8::internal::ScavengeJob::operator=+12855
10: 000000013FB12714 v8::internal::StackGuard::HandleInterrupts+100
11: 000000013F930B57 v8::internal::WasmJs::Install+28023
12: 0000038C7C65C5C1
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

How crazy is the idea of transform this module into `CLI-module` and run it with `child_process.fork()`?

Comment: Repro would be nice. How did you arrived at that?

Comment: You don't need to fork (though you can if you want). You can use worker threads to process something in a separate thread: https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html